# IAP IOS How to add custom pricing?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, react-native-ios

Can't we use the custom pricing in IOS IAP?
Are we restricted to the prices in the pricing tiers?

Comment: You have to select one of the available pricing tiers.

Comment: can't we add our own pricing by any chance

Comment: No, You have to select one of the available pricing tiers